# some dotfiles aren't removed in array of files after deleting entries that start with "."

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io

for some reason there are some files that start with "." in the second `print()` call even they should of been removed in the `for` loop

```
from os import *

cwd = getcwd()                                                                                                                               
cfiles = listdir(cwd)

print(str(cfiles) + "\n")

for files in cfiles:
    if files[0] == ".":
        cfiles.pop(cfiles.index(files))
    else:
        continue

print(cfiles)
```

Comment: Maybe they have space before the dot.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't remove the elements of a list inside a `for` loop. Try something like:

```
from os import *

cwd = getcwd()                                                                                                                               
cfiles = listdir(cwd)

print(str(cfiles) + "\n")
index = 0
while index < len(cfiles):
    files = cfiles[index]
    if files[0] == ".":
        cfiles.pop(cfiles.index(files))
    else:
        index += 1

print(cfiles)
```

Comment: But while debugging, when inside the 'for .. in' loop the items were removed and the list had the updated values at the end. I guess its possible as list is mutable right ?

Comment: The problem with using a `for` loop is that it uses an iterator that gets created at the start of the loop. If elements of the loop are removed, the iterator can get lost.

Comment: Yes! makes sense. The indexing gets mixed up as the elements get shifted to the left as an item is removed. Thanks Jhon

Answer (score 0):

Try this version. It worked fine:

```
from os import *

cwd = getcwd()
cfiles = list()
for file in listdir(cwd):
    if file[0] == ".":
        continue
    else:
        cfiles.append(file)

print(cfiles)
```

But it's pretty strange that a few files in list cfiles (.gitignore and config.yml in my case while debugging) was ignored when 'for.. in' was used with the cfiles.

Hope the solutions helps!